# On the uniqueness of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If we were to exclude the constant, does a first-order differential equation, always have a unique solution? if so, could someone suggest a way of proving this?
This isn't homework, I was just curious.

Comment: Note:- This is all the maths I know:- elementary calculus, the basics of linear algebra, and algebra. So if the proof requires more maths, please just give me an intuitive explaination

Comment: I think you'll be wanting the [existence and uniqueness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem)

Comment: so this would require a lot more than elementary calculus to understand, won't it?

Comment: I wasn't talking about Initial value problems( as the Wikipedia article you linked says), I'm more interested in knowing if a differential equation of the first order always has a unique family of curves as its solution

Comment: What is a unique family of curves ?

Comment: l mean the solution can only be let's say f(x)+C, for instnace ln(x)+C is the only solution of a certain differential equation

Comment: @fhhh If that's what you mean, then that's not the case: $y' = y$ has the solution set $y = Ce^x,$ and there are many other instances where the constant appears in ways other than just an addition at the end. (as far as the connection with IVPs, the point is that the initial values determine the constant)

Comment: I see, thanks, @StephenDonovan

Answer (score 3):

No. For instance if you consider the initial value problem $y' = 2 \sqrt{y}$, $y(0)=0$, you can check that both $y=0$ and $y=x^2$ are solutions.

There are results, like the Picard-Lindelof theorem, that provide conditions for the local existence and uniqueness of solution. These local solutions can be extended to maximal domains of definition (and can sometimes be globally defined).

Comment: I see, thank you!